# Iframes in opened in new tab blocked from top level navigation

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm confused about how the top-level browsing context works in chrome. As per this conversation, an opened window (C in the diagram from the link) has a top-level browsing context. I’ve been working on a similar setup.
[image: window-iframe-snadbox-diagram]

I have an iframe(B) in window(A). Scripts in iframe(B) open a new window(C), which I assume to have a top-level browsing context.

If I am to include another iframe(D) in the opened window(C), which is not sandboxed at all, the content in the iframe should be able to perform top-level navigation in the opened page(C).

This behavior is in chrome, safari, and firefox and the top-level navigation requires the sandbox flags to be set on both iframes B and D. Can someone explain why these flags are required on iframe B even when B is not trying to do top-level navigation and top-level navigation done by D does not affect A?

Comment: If yet have no answer to your question, you should try to make it 'Bountied' in order more users can access your question and maybe have an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Because it would require allow_top_navigation to be special cased, rather than being consistent with all the other sandbox permissions. There probably isn't a sufficiently good use case to justify such special casing.